# Best Design pattern with APEX and a java application?

Tags: json, design-patterns, apex

Currently I'm developing a ToDo List app with some functions such as assigning task to an specific user and to have a master control (Similar to trello or Jira), but I'm working with Apex, any ideas about:

1. Best practices?
2. Request/Response JSON
3. Design pattern

Much appreciated.